# What's the difference of add methods in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Three add methods:
`+`, `tf.add`, `tf.nn.bias_add`.
I made test in ipython, here is the test data.

```
a = tf.Variable([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = tf.Variable([10,20])
```

All three methods returned `array([[11, 22],[13, 24]], dtype=int32)`.
So what's the difference between them?

Thanks!

Comment: bias_add uses faster implementation internally, the other two are the same -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7551#issuecomment-284519625

Answer (score 3):

From the tensorflow documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/bias_add):

> Unlike tf.add, the type of bias is allowed to differ from value in the case where both types are quantized.

`tf.add` is a general addition operation, while `tf.nn.bias_add` is to be used specifically for adding bias to the weights, which raises an exception if the dtypes aren't same.